# How to Answer homework-like questions?

Tags: discussion, homework-and-exercises

Is it a bad way to hint at the solution and, ask them to do what they understood and edit the original question to include their steps, and then they follow it up pointing out the mistakes and correcting them?

I am asking this question because two of my solutions got closed even though I was exactly following this pattern which I thought was right. I am not sure how else I am supposed to approach these questions, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Taking a look through your answers, the deleted ones are all answers to *bad questions*. It’s not you, it’s them.

When you’re trying to decide *whether* to answer a homework-like question, take a moment to think about how you can make your answer useful to *future readers* who might have similar problems. Answers about the conceptual underpinnings of the problem usually can be molded into this kind of a shape. Answers consisting of a vague hint on the one end, or an algebra audit on the other, take much more skill to be useful to anyone other than the author of the question.

Comment: ohh Okay that makes sense... Thank you.